# Why do I get a space instead of a line break?

Tags: hta

Ok, so i am creating an .hta for my job, but i am also using it to help me understand some different coding techniques. So it is entirely possible that I am missing something simple.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
function TransferData()
{
  var textholder = "==============================";
  textholder += "\r\n";
  textholder += "\r\n" + document.getElementById("name").value;
  textholder += "\r\n" + document.getElementById("phone").value;
  textholder += "\r\n" + document.getElementById("email").value;
  document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = textholder;
}
</script>

<textarea id="name" rows="1" cols="30" onkeyup="TransferData()"></textarea>
<textarea id="phone" rows="1" cols="30" onkeyup="TransferData()"></textarea>
<textarea id="email" rows="1" cols="30" onkeyup="TransferData()"></textarea>

<textarea id="outputbox" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Each element ID pulls from a text area and is sent to a text area. If it would be easier to send it to something else, feel free to suggest it. This data cant be saved to anything, and it all has to be run from one document. This data is gathered and then soon after is cleared. Can anyone tell me why "\r\n" is only giving me a space and not a line break?

By the way... if I am miss tagging this post PLEASE TELL ME!

Comment: My guess is because HTML *doesn't use `\r\n`* for end-of-line

Comment: @BrianRoach if it were a `div` or something like that you would be right, but this is a textarea, the problem is that it was set to `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`. See Mikhail Vladimirov's answer.

Comment: For more tags, you could add html in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign to property `value` of your text area, not `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("outputbox").value = textholder;
```

Comment: Mikhail you are awesome! That was the fix, the <br /> had thrown more errors. Thank you guys for the help!